# Ошибка mysql The Error returned was:

Tags: mysql

> MySQL error in file: /engine/inc/addnews.php at line 864 Error Number:
>   1364 The Error returned was: Field 'kp_id_movie' doesn't have a
>   default value

подскажите что за проблема может быть

в строке 864 указано

```
$db->query( "INSERT INTO " . PREFIX . "_post (date, autor, short_story, full_story, xfields, title, descr, keywords, category, alt_name, allow_comm, approve, allow_main, fixed, allow_br, symbol, tags, metatitle) values ('$thistime', '{$author}', '$short_story', '$full_story', '$filecontents', '$title', '{$metatags['description']}', '{$metatags['keywords']}', '$category_list', '$alt_name', '$allow_comm', '$approve', '$allow_main', '$news_fixed', '$allow_br', '$catalog_url', '{$_POST['tags']}', '{$metatags['title']}')" );
```

Comment: Ошибка, скорее всего, связано с тем, что вы не отправляете значение для *недефолтной* колонки `kp_id_movie`.

Comment: все значения отправляются. просто ошибка появилась после переезда на новый сервер с новой версией мускула

Comment: >> *все значения отправляются* Я не увидел в запросе ссылку на колонку `kp_id_movie`. Это может быть связано с версией, поскольку одна версия может игнорировать, что у колонки не выставлено значение по умолчанию, а другая будет ругаться на это.

Answer (score 1):

Поведение при добавлении строки без указания колонки, не имеющей дефолтного значения зависит от того, включен ли SQL [strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

Если strict mode включен, запрос вернёт ошибку. Если выключен - то будет использовано какое-то неявное дефолтное значение этого типа данных. В mysql 5.7 SQL strict mode был включён по-умолчанию.

Хотя пока что strict mode можно отключить, в будущих версиях strict mode могут сделать уже неотключаемым. Лучше укажите для поля дефолтное значение с помощью запроса:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT 'some_default_value';
```

Скорей всего проявятся и другие различия от включенного строгого режима. Судя по прямому подставлению данных в SQL, приложение написано не слишком качественно.